# Nexus Player 5.10.31-leanback developer options

Tags: android-versions

I just purchased Nexus Player after doing a bunch of research on it capabilities. However the one i have appears to be stripped of the "developer options" that will allow me to side load the apps I want. When I click on "Build version" 7 times nothing happens. Is there a way to do this on the new software version?

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to support at Google and Asus it seams the folks at Google removed it. However, if you hard reset the device you'll get the original Asus software and Developer Mode can be entered.